# Using DbFunctions or EF.Function in Entity Framework Core 3.1.7

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-core

LINQ doesn't like DateTime functions `Subtract` and `AddDays`. So I was thinking to use [DBFunction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.datediffday?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions-datediffday(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbfunctions-system-datetimeoffset-system-datetimeoffset)), I am using Entity Framework Core v3.1.7, but I can't access `DateDiffDay()` method.

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.datediffday?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions-datediffday(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbfunctions-system-datetimeoffset-system-datetimeoffset)) it's supported by Entity Framework Core v3.1.7 but when I try to access it `DbFunctions` only shows two options - `Equal` and `ReferenceEquals`:

[image]

Is there anything I need to enable to make other methods available? or Anything I need to make an change on my code to make it work with LINQ?

This is the query I need to replace with `DateDiff` because I keep getting an error

> Could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

My code:

```
var billing = _context.Billing.AsNoTracking()
                     .Select(i => new BillingSearchDTO
                                  {
                                      ID = i.ID,
                                      InvoiceNumber = i.InvoiceNumber,
                                      DaysPastDue = i.InvoiceDetail.Where(i => i.TypeID == TypeID_XT ||
                                                                               i.TypeID == TypeID_XP)
                                                                   .Select(i => i.AmountRemaining)
                                                                   .Sum() > 0 ? DateTime.Now.Subtract(i.Invoicedate.AddDays(i.ProductNav.GracePeriod.GetValueOrDefault())).Days : 0,.Days : 0
});
```

Error:

> Select(i2 => i2.AmountRemaining)
> .Sum() > 0 ? DateTime.Now.Subtract(i.Outer.Invoicedate.AddDays((double)i.Inner.GracePeriod.GetValueOrDefault())).Days : 0 == 656)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
> at ...

Any Help?

Comment: Did you import `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`? `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Comment: @YongShun yes I used `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Comment: You may check whether your project had installed this **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer v6.0.0** package.

Comment: `EF.Functons.DateDiffDays` is extension method for SQL Server. and you need reference for specific EF Core database provider.

Comment: @kukamuk did you ever figure this out?  I am having the same issue